How to ensure image is renderred to 'Konva React' canvas before taking a screenshot in 'Playwright'?
I have written a react component that draws an image to the 'konva react' canvas. The component utilises the useImage hook. The problem is that the canvas will be drawn first and the image will be added to the canvas later. This causes an issue when testing. In my playwright testing I look for a 'canvas' DOM element and take a screenshot to do a visual comparison.
Now, the problem is that 'canvas' will render and the screenshot will be taken before the image is drawn on the canvas. This results in a 'flaky' tests, where sometimes the screenshot is taken before the image is drawn and sometimes after.
Here is a simplified version of the component.

const Figure: React.FC<FigureProps> = ({
  url,
  x,
  y,
}) => {

  const [image] = useImage(url);

  return (
    <Image
      x={x}
      y={y}
      image={image}
    />
  );
};

export default Figure;


So far the most similar question I have found is this. However, the suggested solution to use a callback and the 'useImage' status is not really applicable as playwright only sees whether a component is there or not.
I know I could just implement an arbitrary waiting time, but this is not a robust solution. I would like to have a solution where before the screenshot is taken by 'Playwright' I can be certain that the image has been drawn to the canvas.

I can't run this example (a [mcve] would be good), but normally you wait for the image network request to arrive, or adjust your code to not make the canvas visible until the image is on it, which is probably good practice anyway.

As mentioned in the link you shared, you can use special logic to track loading of your application. From playwright you can watch for loading variable.
Much simplified version of this can be:

window.loadingCount = 0;

const Figure: React.FC<FigureProps> = ({
  url,
  x,
  y,
}) => {

  const [image] = useImage(url);

  // use layout effect for faster execution
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if(image) {
      // image is loaded
      window.loadingCount -= 1;
    } else {
      // image is not loaded yet
      window.loadingCount += 1;
    }

  }, [image]);

  return (
    <Image
      x={x}
      y={y}
      image={image}
    />
  );
};

export default Figure;

Then in playwright you do this:
await page.waitForFunction(() => window.loadingCount === 0);

Just need to make sure that the function will start execution after Figure component is mounted.

Thanks for your answer! I had to modify it a little as I couldn't find a way to wait for the 'Figure' component to mount. I just used a boolean value instead of the counter as I only need one Figure component anyway for testing. I have posted an answer with the solution I ended up using.

Thanks to @lavrton I took some inspiration from the answer and came up with the following solution.

As suggested by @lavrton I used a global variable, but initialised it to a boolean value. The reason for the boolean value is that I don't think it is possible to wait until the Figure component mounts as Playwright only 'sees' the canvas component and nothing within it.


window.ImageLoaded = false;

const Figure: React.FC<FigureProps> = ({
  url,
  x,
  y,
}) => {

  const [image] = useImage(url);

  // use layout effect for faster execution
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      window.ImageLoaded = true;
    }
  });


  return (
    <Image
      x={x}
      y={y}
      image={image}
    />
  );
};

export default Figure;


This is my use case specific, but I hope this might help someone. Since we are using Storybook to test the components and storybook uses frames it is important that within the Playwright test the frame is accessed and then the window, as frames have their own window objects. This is done the following way:

// ...navigation to page code

// access the frame and the window
  await page.frame("storybook-preview-iframe")?.waitForFunction(() => {
    return window.ImageLoaded === true;
  });

//...here we are sure the image is loaded and can do a visual comparison

